# How to convert Wicket application into Wicket Portlet application?

Tags: wicket

I have a complicated Apache Wicket application.I want to convert that application as a Wicket Portlet application. I got some information from https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/portal-howto.html. But doesnt so clear . So wanted to know the simple steps to convert an wicket Application into Wicket Portlet Application

Answer (score 0):

I have done the exact opposite of you, I converted a lot of Wicket Portlet to a single Wicket Application. What portlet container are you going to use ? What Wicket version are you using ? I think Portlet support has been dropped in 1.5, so be warned that you will be stuck with 1.4 unless you provide your patches. The Wiki page you're talking explains everything you have to know. I suggest you try an hello-world before converting your application.

Comment: I am using Wicket 1.4.15 , since is supports portlets . I have tried hello-world wicket portlet also, it works fine. I am using Oracle Weblogic. WSRP is Producer and Vignette is Consumer. Through Vignette we lauch the app. The wiki link https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/portal-howto.html expains only the external configuration like portlet.xml,web.xml, etc. I just wanted to know whether any code changes are required like changing WebPage to portletPage,etc... If any code changes are required,then what are the major changes ?

Comment: I was using Liferay, but to make it short, only a few changes are required (the ones described in the page you're talking about AFAIR)